OpenXML creates XLSX file which needs repairs
Let me preface my question by saying that I have not changed this code in months, it has been working for years, I have not updated or modified external libraries.
I have a C# class that helps in creating/managing XLSX exports. Starting about one week ago, all the files have come out "corrupted". I have analyzed them using the productivity tool and it doesn't detect any error. Moreover, not every file is corrupt.
Let me give you an example. I have a XLSX model that I take as canvas, and insert strings in cells C14, C15, C16, C17... up to C24. Everything up to C23 is fine, but if I start inserting (only in that specific file) text in C24 it inserts it without errors, the XML has the text in the shared strings table and it is correctly referenced, BUT on Excel open it says it will repair the file and delete the text. The text can be any text, I already tried just writing "hi" on it. From the moment it encounters an error onwards, every other text is then skipped and deleted.
Let's go to the code, although it is almost the same as the one found on this page.
On my main program, I write
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(Path.Combine(dialog.FileName, NomeFile), true))
{
    /*spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
    spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;*/

    ExcelExportUtility.InsertText(spreadSheet, progetto.Titolo, "C", 8);
    ExcelExportUtility.InsertText(spreadSheet, docente.Docente, "C", 23);
}

Basically opening the file provided before, then using a static helper class I write in cells C8 and C23.
InsertText is as follows:
public static void InsertText(SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet, object text, string col, int row)
{
    CellValues type = GetExcelType(text);

    string index;
    if (type == CellValues.SharedString)
    {
        index = InsertSharedStringItem(spreadSheet, text.ToString()).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        index = text.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
    }

    // Get worksheet
    WorkbookPart wbPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart;
    IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
    string sheetId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
    WorksheetPart wsPart = (WorksheetPart)wbPart.GetPartById(sheetId);

    // Insert cell into the worksheet.
    Cell cell = InsertCellInWorksheet(col, row, wsPart);
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(index);
    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(type);

    wsPart.Worksheet.Save();
}

It checks what type the object passed it (in this case it outputs SharedString), if it is a string it will update the SharedStrings table and then write it in the cell in the first available sheet.
It works for every cell until I try to write (in this case) in C24. Any other writing i put under C24 will be deleted. Any other string written before that will be writted without problems.
In my model C24 is a normal blank cell (I even deleted a few rows and scrambled averything around, but to no avail).
Again, this is just an example, in almost every XLSX creation in my project there is this problem now, not just this particular model or this particular data.
I am aware that I can convert every SharedString into an internal string, but that will just avoid the problem, not solve it, and it would appear again in the future.

Have you check your storage device (ie: hard drive, SSD, ...) to ensure that it's not starting to fail?

Yes, i've checked it. I should also have said I'm not the only user of this program, other users have notifies me of failing xlsx
